# REACT - Retrieve state of the parent and pass to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and have got to a point where I am a bit stuck. Here is the Parent component of my add with the attribute im using to populate its state with a JSON object:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            clothing:{},
            order:{}
        }   
    },
    loadClothingItems: function(){
        this.setState({clothing:clothing});
    },
});
```

In my render function for App I am passing down the apps props for loadClothingItems like so:

```
<OtherOptions loadClothingItems={this.loadClothingItems} />
```

Here is the child component (OtherOptions). There is an a-tag which onClick populates the App state. I then need to get the state that has been added to App back down to OtherOptions in order to generate all my object key properties into li items within the ul:

```
var OtherOptions = React.createClass({
   render:function(){
       return (
           <div className="other-options-inner">
        <a onClick={this.props.loadClothingItems}>Load Clothing</a>
               <ul>
                   {console.log(this.props.state)}
               </ul>
               </div>
       )
   } 
});
```

When I initially load the app I get a console log of "undefined" which is expected as I have not yet populated the App components state but when I click the a-tag it gives me "undefined again".

I was expecting to the new state of App being passed down to OtherOptions here so I could take the state and render out some li items. Maybe i'm not going about it the right way to communicate with the parent or maybe i'm completely off-track but either way I am stuck and the documentation hasn't helped.

Thanks

Comment: I see that in your `OtherOptions` component, you're trying to access `this.props.state`. When you render `<OtherOptions />`, are you passing a prop called `state`?

Comment: No thats just me trying to get a hold of App's state. Again im a beginner so I could be well off track here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass all of the state to the child component then you can do so via props `<OtherOptions items={this.state} loadClothingItems={this.loadClothingItems} />`
and access it in the child component via `this.props.items`

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in `loadClothingItems`, but `clothing` doesn't exist anywhere so trying to set the state of `clothing` to clothing will be undefined.

Comment: That was it, thanks Eric! Sorry the clothing variable was in my JSON file. If I want to pass down the state to child components do I need to do this every time? Or this this not best practice?

Comment: If you have a lot of data in your app I would look into implementing Redux which will help with state management. Also there is no need to pass the entire state to child components if not all of the state is needed. For example, if you only need to pass the state of clothing to the child then pass `clothing={this.state.clothing}`